# When do we use XMLSerialization?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I was searching on examples as how to store data in isolated storage. In an example XmlSerializer was used. I have given the code below. Please explain the function and need for Xmlserializer.

```
XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(TravelReportInfo));
ser.Serialize(fs, travelReportInfo);
```

Comment: [Read results one and two...](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=XmlSerializer)

Answer (score 1):

XmlSerialization is the process of taking an object and representing it as xml. Xml is one of the ideal formats for this since it can describe arbitrary object hierarchies.
One common use case is transfering objects over the web. If you serialize your object to xml you can include it in http requests and responses and deserialize it back to its original object on the other side. All information to reconstruct the object is found in the xml

Bellow you can see an example of a class serialized to xml

```
public class OrderForm
{
    public DateTime OrderDate;
}

<OrderForm>
    <OrderDate>12/12/01</OrderDate>
</OrderForm>
```